# Is this a proper implementation of Kruskal's algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, kruskals-algorithm

I wrote the following code as a solution to UVA OnlineJudge problem #10034:

```
// problem 10034

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class tree;

class vertex {
public:
    double x,y;
    tree* mTree;
};

class tree {
public:
    tree(tree* last,vertex* v);

    int size();
    void assimilate(tree* other);

    tree* prev;
    tree* next;
    vector<vertex*> vertices;
};

tree::tree(tree* last,vertex* v) {
    prev = last;
    next = NULL;
    vertices.push_back(v);
    v->mTree = this;

    if(last != NULL) {
        last->next = this;
    }
}

int tree::size() {
    return vertices.size();
}

void tree::assimilate(tree* other) {
    int c;

    if(other->prev != NULL) {
    other->prev->next = other->next;
    }

    if(other->next != NULL) {
    other->next->prev = other->prev;
    }

    for(c = 0;c < other->vertices.size();c++) {
        this->vertices.push_back(other->vertices[c]);

        other->vertices[c]->mTree = this;
    }

    delete other;
}

class edge {
public:
    edge() {
        v1 = NULL;
        v2 = NULL;
        weight = 0;
    }

    edge(vertex* a,vertex* b,double w) {
        v1 = a;
        v2 = b;
        weight = w;
    }

    bool operator<(const edge& rhs) const {
        return this->weight < rhs.weight;
    }

    vertex* v1;
    vertex* v2;
    double weight;
};

double dist(double x1,double y1,double x2,double y2) {
    double dx;
    double dy;

    dx = x2 - x1;
    dy = y2 - y1;

    return sqrt((dx*dx) + (dy*dy));
}

int main() {
    int ncases;
    int ccase;
    int c;
    int nverts;
    int nedges;
    edge* edges;
    vertex* vertices;
    tree* lasttree;
    double cost;
    tree* t1;
    tree* t2;
    bool treeexists;
    int cedge;
    int cc;


    cin>>ncases;

    for(ccase = 0;ccase < ncases;ccase++) {
        cin>>nverts;
        nedges = (nverts*(nverts-1)) / 2;

        treeexists = false;
        lasttree = NULL;

        vertices = new vertex[nverts];
        edges = new edge[nedges];
        cedge = 0;

        for(c = 0;c < nverts;c++) {
            cin>>vertices[c].x;
            cin>>vertices[c].y;
            lasttree = new tree(lasttree,&vertices[c]);
        }

        for(c = 0;c < nverts;c++) {
            for(cc = c+1;cc < nverts;cc++) {
                edges[cedge] = edge(vertices+c,vertices+cc,dist(vertices[c].x,vertices[c].y,vertices[cc].x,vertices[cc].y));
                cedge++;
            }
        }

        sort(edges,edges+nedges);

        cost = 0;

        for(c = 0;c < nedges;c++) {
            //cout<<"edge with length "<<edges[c].weight<<endl;

            if(edges[c].v1->mTree != edges[c].v2->mTree) {
                //cout<<"using"<<endl;

                cost += edges[c].weight;

                t1 = edges[c].v1->mTree;
                t2 = edges[c].v2->mTree;

                if(t1->size() > t2->size()) {
                    t1->assimilate(t2);
                } else {
                    t2->assimilate(t1); 
                }
            }
        }

        if(ccase > 0) {
            cout<<endl;
        }

        cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<cost;

        delete vertices[0].mTree;
        delete[] vertices;
        delete[] edges;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It works for both the test case provided with the problem and a larger test case that I found here: http://online-judge.uva.es/board/viewtopic.php?p=21939#p21939

When I submit it to UVA, however, I get a wrong answer message. Is my implementation of Krukal's algorithm correct? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your algorithm correct? This is a lot of code for the average answerer to look through. Try making some test cases and show us the output! Perhaps you could do some debugging on your own and give us a general area to look over. Some comments about your code, and how things *should* be working in each section would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, why aren't you using a [union-find data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) instead of doing complicated manipulations on a pointer structure?

Second, the problem seems to have a nasty trick in it.  You don't just want the minimum spanning tree.  Consider the case

```
4
0.0 0.0
1.0 0.0
1.0 1.0
0.0 1.0
```

I only need 2 sqrt(2) units of ink to connect all of the dots; I make an X our of two lines of length sqrt(2).  However, the minimum spanning tree has length 3.

Comment: Ah sorry I misread your input. Still, I'm not sure if your 2*sqrt(2) solution works for this. It seems to me that in the question you aren't allowed to switch lines when they intersect so your 'X' solution is insufficient. The MST solution for this (if he initializes the graph with edges between all pairs) is actually 2*sqrt(2) + 1 and is correct, from my interpretation.

Comment: The MST has length 3 in that example.  I don't see an obvious bug in your code, but you did make it a lot harder on yourself by using a complicated web of pointers.

Comment: Oh sorry you're right, it's 3. Still, I am not sure your 2*sqrt(2) solution is correct. The original question posted says, "When Richie is done there must be a sequence of connected lines from any freckle to any other freckle." Is 'X' really sufficient? To go from the top left point to the top right point you'd have to change direction at the intersection which I'm not convinced is allowed. Also, I'm not OP